# iMessage on Mac but not iPhone

Tags: messages

I recently swapped my iphone for a samsung galaxy but still have imessages on my macbook. I was hoping to still be able to use imessages on my macbook, however, I am unable to sign into imessages with my apple account, i get the following error:

Could not sign into iMessage. An error occred during activation. Try again.

This has been happening for a week. Can I use imessages on my mac, or must I also have an iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old thread but I just resolved this by contacting apple as it transpired that my nephew's apple id had been suspended. Got the above message when trying to log in to iMessage on iPad and Mac so suspected it was the account rather than device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can active iMessage on your mac with your Apple ID.

"An error occred during activation. Try again" is very general message, Probably because of network problems or problems caused by apple service.